# Android Studio refactoring issue

Tags: java, android

I want to refactor the name of Dealerlist to SnapbackDealerlist.

[image: Class Diagram]

However, Snapbackdealerlist keeps on appearing as a subclass within Dealerlist instead of replacing it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file in the Android Studio project pane and click Refactor -> Rename.  This will rename both the class and the file.